# Is there a way to create speech bubble tutorial using a library in iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a bubble that appears as a user uses the app. Just like that Facebook has in the example below. Is there a way to do it without creating the entire bubble as an image? I'm just skeptical that an entire image would do as well.

[Facebook tutorial bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOfpG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want you can achieve with this library: [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView)!

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! been googling all night but somehow didn't manage to find it